# CADFtest critical values?

Tags: r, unit-root, augmented-dickey-fuller

I just came across the [CADF test package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/CADFtest/vignettes/CADFtest.pdf) and have a question related to the critical values. As I understand [this source](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v032i02), the CADF test allows to test with the modified AIC (MAIC) by Ng and Perron (2001).

```
library(CADFtest)
data(nporg)
df <- nporg[complete.cases(nporg), ]

# CADFtest
CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="AIC", type="drift")
# urca
summary(ur.df(df$emp, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift")) # -0.2585 > -2.89
# CADFtest
CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="MAIC", type="drift")
# cval
ur.df(df$emp, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift")@cval
```

Output:

```
> CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="AIC", type="drift")

    ADF test

data:  df$emp
ADF(1) = -0.25852, p-value = 0.9243
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
       delta 
-0.004570065 

> # urca
> summary(ur.df(df$emp, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift")) # -0.2585 > -2.89

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression drift 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5442.2 -1047.6   272.6  1103.6  3577.1 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 669.92912  963.39684   0.695 0.489641    
z.lag.1      -0.00457    0.01768  -0.259 0.796934    
z.diff.lag    0.44514    0.12197   3.650 0.000571 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1764 on 57 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1929,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1646 
F-statistic: 6.812 on 2 and 57 DF,  p-value: 0.002225


Value of test-statistic is: -0.2585 1.5599 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.51 -2.89 -2.58
phi1  6.70  4.71  3.86

> # CADFtest
> CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="MAIC", type="drift")

    ADF test

data:  df$emp
ADF(1) = -0.25852, p-value = 0.9243
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
       delta 
-0.004570065 

> # cval
> ur.df(df$emp, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift")@cval
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.51 -2.89 -2.58
phi1  6.70  4.71  3.86
```

**The test computes p-values, but unlike the ur.df test doesn't show any critical values. Do I assume correctly that they are the same, only the lag selection" is different in MAIC?**

What seems different though is the result when setting a maximum lag of 4:

```
# urca
summary(ur.df(df$emp, lags = 4, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift"))
ur.df(df$emp, lags = 4, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift")@lags # uses lag 4
# CADFtest
CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="MAIC", max.lag.y = 4, type="drift") # uses lag 2(?)
CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="AIC", max.lag.y = 4, type="drift") # uses lag 2(?)
```

Output:

```
> summary(ur.df(df$emp, lags = 4, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift"))

############################################### 
# Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Unit Root Test # 
############################################### 

Test regression drift 


Call:
lm(formula = z.diff ~ z.lag.1 + 1 + z.diff.lag)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5101.9  -824.4    43.6  1061.8  3571.6 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  4.622e+02  1.052e+03   0.439 0.662145    
z.lag.1      9.204e-04  1.921e-02   0.048 0.961969    
z.diff.lag1  5.299e-01  1.358e-01   3.902 0.000271 ***
z.diff.lag2 -2.081e-01  1.376e-01  -1.512 0.136523    
---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1

Residual standard error: 1789 on 53 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.2272,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.1835 
F-statistic: 5.194 on 3 and 53 DF,  p-value: 0.003212


Value of test-statistic is: 0.0479 1.9212 

Critical values for test statistics: 
      1pct  5pct 10pct
tau2 -3.51 -2.89 -2.58
phi1  6.70  4.71  3.86

> ur.df(df$emp, lags = 4, selectlags = "AIC", type = "drift")@lags # uses lag 4
[1] 4
> CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="MAIC", max.lag.y = 4, type="drift") # uses lag 2(?)

    ADF test

data:  df$emp
ADF(2) = 0.047908, p-value = 0.9587
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
      delta 
0.000920429 

> CADFtest(df$emp, criterion="AIC", max.lag.y = 4, type="drift") # uses lag 2(?)

    ADF test

data:  df$emp
ADF(2) = 0.047908, p-value = 0.9587
alternative hypothesis: true delta is less than 0
sample estimates:
      delta 
0.000920429
```

Would be great to have a feedback on that.

Comment: In the code you only show the commands but no output. I guess having the relevant output could be helpful.

Comment: I just inserted the output and hope someone will have ti patience to look at it.

Answer (score 0):

CADFtest() function performs a unit root test based on the p-value, not the test statistic.

You need to decide I(0) or I(1) when you see p-value = 0.123 for example.
The distribution can be expressed as a combination of (1) the DF distribution used for the ADF test and (2) the standard normal distribution. The p-value based on the DF distribution is obtained by setting "rho2=1" in CADFpavlues () function.

Example codes are shown in the below.

##### start CADF test

## Covariates should be stationary.

eq_y1 <- y1[-1] ~ y2_diff + y3_diff + y4_diff

eq_y1_CADF <- CADFtest(eq_y1, type = "trend", max.lag.y = 5,
min.lag.X = 0, max.lag.X = 5, criterion = "MAIC")

summary.CADFtest(eq_y1_CADF)

plot.CADFtest(eq_y1_CADF)

##### end of CADF

##### start ADF test

y1_ADF <- CADFtest(y1, type = "trend", max.lag.y = 5,
criterion = "MAIC")

summary.CADFtest(y1_ADF)

plot.CADFtest(y1_ADF)

CADFpvalues(y1_ADF$stastic, rho2 = 1, type = "trend")

##### end of ADF